# Linked List Head getting overwritten by tail

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to get use to C by implementing different data structures. I am having an issue where when I try to initialize a linked list from command line inputs per while loop iterations, the head keeps getting set to the tail, which is the last command inputted into stdin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char value[512];
    struct node *next;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node **curr = &head;
    int flag = 1;
    int c = 0;

    while(flag == 1)
    {
        char cmd[512];
        struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        fgets(cmd, 512, stdin);
        cmd[strcspn(cmd, "\n")] = 0;

        if (strcmp(cmd,"exit") ==0){
            printf("Exiting\n");
            break;            
        } else {
            strncpy(new_node->value, cmd, 512);
            new_node->value[512 - 1] = '\0';
            (*curr)->next = new_node;
            *curr = new_node;
        }
    }

    printf("head value: %s\n", head->value);
    printf("curr value: %s", (*curr)->value);


    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand why head->value and curr->value end up being the same. Any input is appreciated along with any convention fixes. I am not sure I am writing C in the expected way.

Thanks,

I tried to use different pointer combinations, and I have also tried to copy the command line entry rather than hard setting it.

Comment: *"I can't understand why head->value and curr->value end up being the same."* -- could you explain why you think they should **not** be the same? You appear to intend that they start the same (initializing `curr = &head`). So I guess this explanation would consist of pointing to where in the code `curr` is assigned a new value. (Hint: You might know where it is *supposed* to be assigned a new value, but is it *actually* `curr` that is assigned a value?)

Comment: Do you want to insert new nodes at the start of the list or at the end of the list?

Comment: You never change `curr` anywhere in the loop, so `*curr` always refers to `head`.  So `*curr = new_node;` in the loop is equivalent to `head = new_node;`  So it's no surprise that `head` changes every time a new node is added.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I want to insert at the start, I intended of having the head be NULL for some arbitrary reason just so I can skip over to the real head after i have populated my list fully from command line inputs

Comment: @cquestions: I have now added a code example to my answer which inserts nodes to the start of the linked list.

Comment: @cquestions: I have now also added a solution to my answer which inserts nodes to the end of the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you want to insert new nodes to the start of the list or to the end of the list.

If you want to insert new nodes to the start of the list, then you must update `head` after every list insertion and set the `next` member of the new node to the old `head`.

If you instead want to insert new nodes to the end of the list, then you must make `curr` always point to the `next` member of the last node of the list, or make it point to `head` if the list is empty.

You appear to be applying neither of the two options described above. Instead, you are making `curr` always point to `head` and making `head` always point to the most recently created node. You are also making the `next` pointer of the previous head node point to the new head node. In other words, you are making the `next` pointers point in the wrong direction. The `next` pointers should always point away from the head, not toward the head.

Here is an example program which inserts nodes at the start of the linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 512

struct node {
    char value[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    struct node *next;
};

int main( void )
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        char cmd[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
        struct node *new_node;

        //read one line of input
        if ( fgets( cmd, sizeof cmd, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Input failure!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        cmd[strcspn(cmd,"\n")] = '\0';

        //check whether user wants to quit
        if ( strcmp( cmd, "exit" ) == 0 )
        {
            printf("Exiting\n");
            break;            
        }

        //allocate new node
        new_node = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
        if ( new_node == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation failure!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //set value of new node
        strcpy( new_node->value, cmd );

        //make new node point to old head
        new_node->next = head;

        //set head to new node
        head = new_node;
    }

    //print content of linked list
    printf( "\nThe head points to the address %p.\n", head );
    for ( struct node *p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next )
    {
        printf(
            "Node at address %p\n"
            "  has the value \"%s\"\n"
            "  and points to the address %p.\n",
             (void*)p, p->value, (void*)p->next
        );
    }

    //free the nodes
    for ( struct node *p = head; p != NULL; )
    {
        struct node *temp = p->next;
        free( p );
        p = temp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
node1
node2
node3
exit
Exiting

The head points to the address 0x559eea92aad0.
Node at address 0x559eea92aad0
  has the value "node3"
  and points to the address 0x559eea92a8c0.
Node at address 0x559eea92a8c0
  has the value "node2"
  and points to the address 0x559eea92a6b0.
Node at address 0x559eea92a6b0
  has the value "node1"
  and points to the address (nil).
```

Here is an example program which instead inserts nodes at the end of the linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 512

struct node {
    char value[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    struct node *next;
};

int main( void )
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node **pp_next = &head;

    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        char cmd[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
        struct node *new_node;

        //read one line of input
        if ( fgets( cmd, sizeof cmd, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Input failure!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        cmd[strcspn(cmd,"\n")] = '\0';

        //check whether user wants to quit
        if ( strcmp( cmd, "exit" ) == 0 )
        {
            printf("Exiting\n");
            break;            
        }

        //allocate new node
        new_node = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
        if ( new_node == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation failure!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //set value of new node
        strcpy( new_node->value, cmd );

        //make new node point to NULL
        new_node->next = NULL;

        //link new node to existing list
        *pp_next = new_node;

        //update pp_next to point to the new NULL pointer
        pp_next = &new_node->next;
    }

    //print content of linked list
    printf( "\nThe head points to the address %p.\n", head );
    for ( struct node *p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next )
    {
        printf(
            "Node at address %p\n"
            "  has the value \"%s\"\n"
            "  and points to the address %p.\n",
             (void*)p, p->value, (void*)p->next
        );
    }

    //free the nodes
    for ( struct node *p = head; p != NULL; )
    {
        struct node *temp = p->next;
        free( p );
        p = temp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
node1
node2
node3
exit
Exiting

The head points to the address 0x5568056a06b0.
Node at address 0x5568056a06b0
  has the value "node1"
  and points to the address 0x5568056a08c0.
Node at address 0x5568056a08c0
  has the value "node2"
  and points to the address 0x5568056a0ad0.
Node at address 0x5568056a0ad0
  has the value "node3"
  and points to the address (nil).
```